# Root finding in [0,1]

Tags: reductions, polynomials

I am interested in the problem of finding a real root of a polynomial equation $f(x)=0$ where
$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$. Is it possible to give a reduction, i.e, to compute a different polynomial $g$ in polytime such that $f$ has a real root iff $g$ has a real root in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right SE forum for it, but the answer is yes.

I'll give the reduction in two steps:

1. $f(x)$ has a root iff $h(x)$ has a root in [-1,1] (scaling, i.e. $h(x)=f(\alpha \cdot x)$).
2. $h(x)$ has a root in [-1,1] iff $g(x)$ has a root in [0,1] (simply define $g(x)=h(\frac{x+1}{2})$).

Let's prove 1:

Let's assume $f(x)$ is of degree $n$ and write it as $f(x) = x^n - a_{n-1} x^{n-1} - ... - a_0$.

If $\alpha \leq 1$, then all of the roots of $f$ in [-1,1] will end up in [-1,1] in $h$.

Let $x$ be a root of $f$ such that $|x|>1$. This means $x^n = a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_0$.

since $|x|>1$, $|x^n| > x^{n-1},x^{n-2},...,1$ hence $$|x| \le \text{max}(1, |a_{n-1}| + ... + |a_0|).$$

Define $\alpha = \text{max}(1, |a_{n-1}| + ... + |a_0|)$ and you're done.

Comment: I think you want $h(x)=f(x / \alpha)$.

Comment: Note that this approach can cause a blowup in the height of the coefficients; it's not clear (to me) whether or not this can be done without a substantial blowup in height or degree, though I suspect you need one or the other...

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative to the answer by R B ; It is somewhat simpler, but has the disadvantage of an increase in degree.

Simply take $g(x) = x^{2n}f(x)f(-x)f(1/x)f(-1/x)$.

Comment: Also, you can make a hybrid of the approaches (simple and not-that-much-higher degree) with: $g(x) = (\frac{x+1}{2})^nf(\frac{x+1}{2})f(\frac{2}{x+1})$.

Comment: I think you meant $g(x) = (2x-1)^n f(2x-1) f(1/(2x-1))$, but yes.